Is it a bad idea to talk about the city/country in phd application letters?
Obviously not the primary focus, but briefly mentioning things like atmosphere and standard of living as one of my motivations for applying to the program... Is this a waste of space? Does it come across superficial? Or maybe it shows realistic interest beyond the material that could be sent to any university in the world?

My advisor suggested mentioning a personal connection or reason because it shows genuine interest and helps you stand out, as most people don’t do it. Just one or two specific lines at the beginning are enough. For example, referencing a hike around, a local attraction, or something unique about the city/country is more impactful than a generic statement like ‘I love this place’.

It could be helpful in a small way, by signaling that you are more likely to enroll if admitted, and that you are not just copy-pasting the same statement to every program you apply to. So it's fine to include this, but I wouldn't devote more than a sentence or two to it.

Having served on PhD admissions committees a fair few times, I’d definitely agree with this answer.  This sort of point certainly shouldn’t be given much space or prominence, compared to more academically substantial issues, but a small mention near the end of a cover letter is never bad.

Since this is a professional application, I'd suggest that while any implication of economic or cultural freeloading will be inappropriate, an acknowledgment that the region produced notable workers in the field and an aspiration to meet their associates and students might be read with appreciation.

If the location and the university are both seen as desirable by most people, I'd recommend not mentioning it. People evaluating your CV will want to be confident that you are very interested in the research and not primarily motivated by the opportunity to move somewhere better. After all, if the location is your primary motivation, you might not find yourself very motivated to excel in your PhD once you arrive.
If the location or university will be seen by many as less desirable, then it might be worth mentioning why you like them, because that might help to alleviate any doubts that you will actually take up the offer. For example, if you have a CV that could easily get you into a much better-known university, they might wonder whether they are your safety school and might prefer to make an offer to a student who will be more likely to take it up. Or if the location is one that many people would dislike (e.g., too hot, too cold and wet, or too small and isolated) but you like those things about it, they may be reassured to know that you will do well there. Still, make sure it doesn't look like your main motivation.

"if the location is your primary motivation, you might not find yourself very motivated to excel" That may describe younger applicants perhaps? And even then - when I was young, I did better in nicer places. I can't explain why but so it was. If I was going for a yet another degree, I'd definitely be motivated by the environs to a good degree. A nice place makes thinking go much better for me, and makes me more upbeat and willing to work hard. I'm sure I'm not the only one? I'm an adult in the "middle" of a career for reference. I've moved just to be in a nicer place a few times :)

I would not bother with remarks about the location that are "generic" in the sense that almost everyone would praise Sydney's location and food or the cultural offerings in London.
What could make sense is statements about the location that are specific to you (and would potentially contribute to your success in the new location) -- family members or significant others living (or moving) there, having lived in the country in the past, significant cultural connections, such as fluency in the language (if it is not broadly spoken).

It depends on the location.
Someone I know well interviewed for a PhD position in an institute north of the Arctic Circle.  Snow on the ground from October to May, three weeks of mosquito-infested summer per year, more than 1000 km from the nearest major city where interesting cultural events happen, connected by maybe one flight per day (weather permitting), winter temperatures often between -20°C and -30°C, but sometimes -40°C, and six weeks during which the Sun doesn't rise at all.  The panellists had experience with candidates dropping out either before or after starting.  Some panellists more or less drilled her with the reasons why their place sucks, and would she still want it?  She successfully convinced them that she did, although did have some doubts when her first day at work had such a bad snowstorm that she got stuck and had to call for help to get to work at all (bad by her western European standards, not by local standards).
(One could equally describe the place as: an outdoor paradise, in particular for skiers; a huge wilderness where you can enjoy the midnight sun or the northern lights during a break from work; a wonderful community where people organise their own fun and therefore make friends more easily than in the city — I loved interrupting my PhD writing for a forest hike at 01:00 in the night — but not everyone views it that way — a Russian visitor once asked: "how much extra do you get to live here?", much to our amusement.)
In my experience, if you are applying in a location that not everyone might consider attractive, it is worth convincing the panel that you can tolerate or even thrive living there.  This is not necessary when applying in a big city.  I find that people in big cities are somewhat surprised if people say they would enjoy living there (of course they would love living in New York/London/Paris/Berlin/Toronto/Barcelona, why do they even need to say this, everybody does), whereas people in smaller or remote towns are more humble in that sense.  Personally I find that unfair, because I would take the remote northern town over an alpha world city any day, but I find it is what people expect.


Works the other way too: "I know your campus paradise by the beach with year-round summer weather has an ultra high cost of living such that even faculty can't afford housing, so I'm content living in a 8-person home and have money saved up so that 85% of my stipend can go to rent."

@user71659 Maybe.  I don't have experience with it myself.  Do such campuses have problems with people dropping out when they realise they were too optimistic about making ends meet with extremely high cost of living?

winter temperatures often between -20°C and -30°C, but sometimes -40°C, and six weeks during which the Sun doesn't rise at all My kind of a place :) I can hide in the mosquito season and go out when it's cold :) It actually sounds amazing, I'm not exaggerating. For sure it'd not be everyone's favorite, though. But then there are people happy as clams living in say Florida, where I'd have been just about miserable. Different strokes for different folks. Are snowball fights allowed? :)

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I loved it, but climate and remoteness are a show-stopper for quite some people (my professor was happy there, but among the reasons he moved south is because recruiting is easier in a more central place), and as I said, a Russian visitor assumed people would get extra to live there (they do in Russia).  Snowball fights don't work at -30°C, the snow is too dry and the snow too powdry.  But you can make clouds by throwing hot water into the air.

@gerrit Sometimes; it contributes to people leaving with a master's. It also has caused grad students to get a secret side job, which severely drags out their time, but that also happens in itself, at least until the savings run low.

This can be very subtle, but I would suggest not dwelling too much on it or spending too many words when other ideas are more important.
Most people want to go to graduate school for, in part, reasons related to standard of living, though academia is unlikely to make you rich monetarily. The rewards are elsewhere. Likewise, many choose schools based on location.
But a few words about background in poverty might not be inappropriate as long as you put the focus on more vital things related to the application. The opposite, saying you are interested in the culture or economic situation of another country or place is even less useful unless that is related to the field of study.
For example, in a Statement of Purpose, focus on what your goals are for graduate school, especially research, and beyond. In letters of recommendation that you write for another person, focus on their skills and the (hopefully) high likelihood of success in meeting requirements and their goals. A few words about "overcoming" unfortunate backgrounds might be ok, but if that is the main focus it won't work. People don't get admitted because other people feel sorry for them.
Nor are they likely to admit a person in, say, mathematics, because they express a desire to explore French culture and language.

Note that this answer may be a bit broader than the specific concerns of the OP, though I hope it helps future readers as well.
